# Update libraries in Web Application using SVN

Tags: svn

here's what I want to do:

1) start developing a new web app, using a few frameworks and libraries
2) store it in SVN
3) update regularly the libraries and frameworks to the latest version, directly from their SVN servers

Do you have any advice on how to update those libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, You can use the [`externals' property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) of SVN to "soft link" to other SVN repositories. I.e. in your repository:

```
src\
tests\
lib1\
framework2\
```

`lib1` can be an empty directory with an `externals` property linking to the SVN repo of that library. When you update your sandbox, the data will be pulled out into that directory. You can also restrict it to a certain revision/tag of the library. Same with `framework2` and anything else you need.

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries is not your own, using Maven or Ivy will be a better solution. You can also start your own Maven repository in the company.

Furthermore, an auto builder that generate the Jar and publish the Jar automatically to your Maven repository can be considered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'll stick with SVN for compatibility issues :)